# DoCmd.OpenForm Compile Error, "Expected: ="

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to run a simple DoCmd.Open Form code and I can't figure out the syntax. What is wrong with this code?

I have tried formatting the Where condition with and without quotes.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm("frm_InvoiceDetail",acNormal, , "[Invoice_]= '" & Me.txtInvNum & "'")

DoCmd.OpenForm("frm_InvoiceDetail",acNormal, , "[Invoice_]=" & Me.txtInvNum)
```

I just want to open the form where the Invoice number equal the invoice number of the clicked textbox. It is giving me a compile error expected:=

Comment: Ditch the parentheses, they don't belong there.

Comment: Thank you @Erik A, that was the problem. It's working now.